# Open Office Documents from an HTML file

Tags: html, pdf, ms-office

I have several Office files and PDFs I want to open from an HTML file. I don't want to embed them in the page. Just open a certain file in e.g. Word, that I have the address of. I read that opening local files from a server is not possible. It is not absolutely necessary to be able to have the HTML file on a server, but if possible that would be a neater solution.

My first naive tries were href(address) and javascript.runProgram(address). This seems to be more complicated, then I thought.

SOLUTION: I found a workaround. At least Firefox you can automatically open filetypes with their corresponding applications. You then specify the file with **href="file:///name.docx"** and choose "always open this filetype automatically".

Comment: Where are the files located? How is the HTML file being served? (Is it being served from a web-server over the public Internet, a LAN web-server, or `http://localhost` server, or being read directly from disk using `file:///`?).

Comment: The files a stored in a local folder. The HTML file is located locally as well, but since I want to run the GUI one 20+ machines, it would be nice to store them on an intranet server for update purposes. I would have to ask someone what type of server it is.

Comment: Is this a company/organization? If so, a pragmatic solution would be to to use OneDrive, OneDrive-for-Business, or SharePoint - which is how Microsoft wants documents to be shared (including editing) between users. If you want your own HTML page only on your network you can still link to OneDrive/OD4B/SP-hosted pages using the "Share using a link" feature to generate the `href=""` value.

Comment: Yes, it is a company. I hope it is not a problem to ask a question for such purposes. The file is already mirrored from SharePoint to OneDrive. I want to open files locally, because it is much faster than opening them from SharePoint.