# How to open excel application by html or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to open excel application by html or java script

I want to open excle file by html or javascript just call excel application

Comment: Could you describe the research you have done and what you have tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

this is a way do Display Office-Documents on a website: [Embed Microsoft Documents in HTML Page](https://www.codexworld.com/embed-microsoft-word-excel-documents-in-html-web-page/)

If you want to open the file in MS Office, if it’s installed, use a link element. At least Firefox you can automatically open filetypes with their corresponding applications. Specify the file with href="file:///name.docx" and choose "always open this filetype automatically".

This is also answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821492/open-office-documents-from-an-html-file).